# dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier is returning nil for cell, but dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier isn't

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm adding a footer to a table view using a prototype cell in Interface Builder:

[image]

When instantiating the footer, `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier()` is returning nil for cell, but `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier()` isn't. I've created a footer view with the correct identifier in Interface Builder:

[image]

And then I instantiate the footer:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let id = "MyFooter"
//    this works:
//    guard let footerCell = self.todaysChoresTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(id) else { 
//        return nil 
//    }
    guard let footerCell = self.todaysChoresTableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(id) else {
        // this doesn't, always returning nil
        return nil
    }
}
```

Why is `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier()` always returning nil?

```
(lldb) po self.tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(id)
nil

(lldb) po self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(id)
▿ Optional(<UITableViewCell: 0x7fa313c835f0; frame = (0 0; 600 44); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa313c73150>>)
  - Some : <UITableViewCell: 0x7fa313c835f0; frame = (0 0; 600 44); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa313c73150→
```

#### Update:

I've tried doing this too, and while now it isn't `nil` anymore, it doesn't seem to actually build a view based on my IB design:

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewHeaderFooterView.self, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: id)
let footerView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView? = self.todaysChoresTableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier(id)
footerView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
return footerView
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried registering the NIB in code using:

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MyFooter", bundle: nil), forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "MyFooterID")
```

Comment: I tried using `registerClass`, but this isn't a nib - it's a prototype cell designed in IB on the cell itself.

Comment: I wasn't aware that prototype _cells_ can be used as footers, are you sure this isn't the problem? If it is, I would suggest making the footer in a nib and using `registerNib`.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should just do that to avoid this ridiculousness

Answer (score 2):

iOS SDK changed behaviour at some point.

As of iOS 10, my app dequeue which uses `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` but it returns nil. Previously, in iOS 8 and 9, it dequeues properly.

My fix is to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` instead, and return the view with `cell.contentView`.

Alternatively, [use a nib and register it](http://samwize.com/2015/11/06/guide-to-customizing-uitableview-section-header-footer/).

Comment: I think that sounds like `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier` working the way it's supposed to. If you read the doco it states "Returns a UITableViewHeaderFooterView object with the associated identifier or nil if no such object exists in the reusable view queue".